# Quiero ver el LOG de una migración de una Base de Datos

Tags: sql

Quiero saber si se hizo una migración de BD desde sql server 2008 a sql server 2012?

Existe un LOG donde se guarda este tipo de operación o puedo saber por Query?

Gracias